# Loading tree of relations at once

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I've got model called Post:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    poster = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='Text', max_length=1000)
    reply_to = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

This allows to add 'first post' (with blank reply_to), and reply to post and even 'reply to reply'

For example I've got in my database something like that:

```
First Post
    Reply one
        Reply to reply one
    Reply two
        Reply to reply two
```

How to load that tree of replies?

When I use:

```
r = Post.objects.filter(reply_to=FirstPost)
```

It returns of course:

```
Reply one
Reply two
```

Is it possible to load all related posts at once?
I need it mainly to count all replies to first post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use MPTT (http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/tutorial.html#the-problem). I have not used this library before so let me know how it goes.

## models.py

```
class Post(MPTTModel):
    poster = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='Text', max_length=1000)
    parent = models.TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['poster']
```

## views.py

```
 ....
 r = FirstPost.get_children()
```

Comment: Cool, this implements what I advocate in a simple add-on package.

Comment: Right, I have used this app before and @victor response hits the target.

Comment: Looks great! I'll try it soon.

Comment: @Victor'Chris'Cabral I had to let you know: MPTT works very good. I think it should be by default in Django. By the way function that I need is get_descendants(), not get_children(). Thank you for this anyway.

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad it worked so well. Is your project open source? Or can you publish some code?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there is a way to load all replies at once.

But, you can add extra metadata to the post type to be able to run a in-order-style query, where counting the number of replies becomes a simple calculation with data already loaded for the parents node.

See [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) on how you could do that (it uses the MySQL SQL dialect, and PHP, but the principles still apply).

Basically, you add `left` and `right` fields to the nodes in your tree that define an ordering, letting you easily count the number of items *below* a given root element in the tree. It's like a Binary Tree in a database table. The principle is taken from this excellent database design book: ["Joe Celko's Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558609202).